# Query datasets with "variable" named slots

Tags: dataset, query, slot

I want to query a `Dataset` object, e.g. select some entries using

```
d = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}];
d[Select[Slot["a"] > 3 &]]
```

which works just fine, but now I want to select entries using a dynamic specification of the column key - like this:

```
colname = "a";
d[Select[Slot[colname] > 3 &]]
```

but this only gives the following error:

```
Function::slot: Slot[colname] (in Slot[colname]>3&) should contain a non-negative integer. >>
```

Am I doing it wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Using V10.2...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These work:

```
d[Select[#[colname] > 3 &]]
```

In the **Details** section of [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), it is said that **"# is equivalent to Slot[1]"**

so it is equivalent to write:

```
d[Select[Slot[1][colname] > 3 &]]
```

Comment: Nice answer. Although I still find it not the most intuitive answer... If `#"column name"` works, then it would seem reasonable for #(colname) to work as the parens should indicate that the variable should be evaluated first...

Answer (score 10):

@SquareOne's answer shows the natural, idiomatic way to express the query.  It exploits the fact that an association can be applied to a key to extract that key's value.  A similar work-around would use part notation:

```
d[Select[#[[colname]] > 3 &]]
```

This response will show how to achieve the desired result using only `Slot` notation.  The motivation is purely academic -- in normal code I would use @SquareOne's answer.

The argument to `Slot` is not evaluated when it appears within a `Function`.  This is true even when using simple numeric slot references in earlier versions of *Mathematica* before the introduction of named slots:

```
n = 1;
Slot[n] &
(* Function::slot: Slot[n] (in Slot[n]&) should contain a non-negative integer. >> *)
```

When such evaluation is desired it must be done externally and then injected into the held expression.  For example:

```
With[{c = colname}, Slot[c] > 3 &]
(* #a > 3 & *)
```

or

```
colname /. c_ :> (Slot[c] > 3 &)
(* #a > 3 & *)
```

In the original context, we could get the desired result by writing:

```
d[Select[With[{c = colname}, Slot[c] > 3 &]]]
```

This is notationally inferior to @SquareOne's solution, but might be useful in more complex scenarios that involve, for example, code generation.

Beware that this injection technique will only work if the `Slot` expression is written in full form.  If we try to perform this replacement using the short form (`#c`), the replacement will fail:

```
With[{c = colname}, #c > 3 &]
(* #c > 3 & *)
```

Note carefully that we ended up with `#c` in the result, not the desired `#a`.  The reason for this is subtle and is revealed by inspecting the full form of the slot reference:

```
#c // FullForm
(* Slot["c"] *)
```

Pay close attention to the fact that the full form involves the string `"c"` and not the symbol `c`.  Therefore, the `With` statement does nothing to the function expression `#c > 3 &` because all it sees is `Slot["c"] > 3 &` with no mention of the symbol `c`.

---

**Why does `Slot[1][colname]&` work when `Slot[colname]&` doesn't?**

As noted in a comment, it is interesting to contrast the behaviours of `Slot[1][colname]&` and `Slot[colname]&`.

We will use simplified examples with the following definition:

```
a = <| "x" -> 123 |>;
```

Recall that keys can be extracted from associations by using function call syntax, or by using part syntax:

```
a["x"]
(* 123 *)

a[["x"]]
(* 123 *)
```

This works even if the key name is stored in a variable:

```
colname = "x";

a[colname]
(* 123 *)

a[[colname]]
(* 123 *)
```

This behaviour remains valid even if the association is passed as an argument to a pure function:

```
#[colname]&[a]
(* 123 *)

#[[colname]]&[a]
(* 123 *)
```

In these cases, `colname` remains unevaluated within the function body but is evaluated when the function is executed.

We can also write these expressions using the full form of `#`:

```
# // FullForm
(* Slot[1] *)

Slot[1][colname]&[a]
(* 123 *)

Slot[1][[colname]]&[a]
(* 123 *)
```

These expressions all work because both function call syntax and part syntax evaluate their keys as a matter of course.

All of this is in contrast to the use of `Slot[colname]` which, as noted in the first section, never evaluates the slot value and is thus invalid syntax.  We are informed of this error even if simply try to define a function that uses it:

```
Slot[colname]&
(* Function::slot:Slot[colname](in Slot[colname]&) should contain a non-negative integer.
   Slot[colname] &
*)
```

If we go so far as to define *and* call the function, we get the error twice:

```
Slot[colname]&[a]
(* Function::slot:Slot[colname](in Slot[colname]&) should contain a non-negative integer.
   Function::slot:Slot[colname](in Slot[colname]&) should contain a non-negative integer.
   (Slot[colname]&)[<|x->123|>]
*)
```

The first message comes from defining the function, and the second from calling the function.  `colname` remains unevaluated within the function body and also when the function is executed.

Comment: Part of this interesting explanations can also be found in the message error doc. of [`Function::slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Function/slot.html).

Comment: Any idea how `Slot[1][colname]&` "works" ? It does not produce an error and the argument is not evaluated ... ?

Comment: @SquareOne See the newly added section _Why does `Slot[1][colname]&` work when `Slot[colname]&` doesn't?_