# Dataset Processing: efficient ways to clean and merge sets for Life Sciences

Tags: dataset

## Dataset Processing (for Life Sciences)

Note: a related, but distinct task is posted here [ID Swapping: Efficient use of a reference table to convert ID values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128696/42578).

A common task, at least for me, involves analyzing at least two different `Datasets`.

A common example, at least currently in biological sciences, involve gene lists. Depending on where they came from, who processed them, which pipeline they were processed with, etc they might vary in form.

For example, consider the following two `Datasets`:

[image]

In Dataset One (`d1`) we see that there are two conditions `c1` and `c2` with various replicates, e.g. `{c1_1, c1_2, c1_3}`. In Dataset Two (`d2`) we do not have the issue of replicates. However, in both sets we have duplicate ids, with varying values in their columns. Biologically this might arise if one converted the transcript id (a subset of the gene) to the gene id. Lastly, not all genes are in both sets. Therefore we have some preprocessing to do:

- find those IDs common to both sets
- combining into a singular `Dataset`
- find duplicates rows (e.g. same value in the ID column)
- average those duplicates rows by column value
- replace those duplicates with their average
- find replicates in the column headers
- average those columns together

i.e. applying the above transformations to given datasets, we should end up with:

[image]

There are a lot of ways to approach this problem. Below I am including what I made to answer this post. However I am sure it is not the most efficient (or most elegantly coded) method. Thus I would appreciate your assistance in finding better ways at this kind of pre-processing.

Shout out to @OneSquare 's answer on [Variable named slots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95947/42578).

Here are the "datasets" used:

```
d1=Dataset@{<|"Gene" -> "a", "c1_1" -> 0.0862185, "c1_2" -> 0.591649, 
  "c1_3" -> 0.119653, "c2_1" -> 0.329605, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.953679|>, <|"Gene" -> "b", "c1_1" -> 0.0837976, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.408317, "c1_3" -> 0.427002, "c2_1" -> 0.373136, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.0670787|>, <|"Gene" -> "c", "c1_1" -> 0.331962, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.389325, "c1_3" -> 0.673205, "c2_1" -> 0.346972, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.784099|>, <|"Gene" -> "d", "c1_1" -> 0.460994, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.376045, "c1_3" -> 0.0499006, "c2_1" -> 0.165925, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.547476|>, <|"Gene" -> "e", "c1_1" -> 0.0474756, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.721516, "c1_3" -> 0.0866807, "c2_1" -> 0.754684, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.00415091|>, <|"Gene" -> "f", "c1_1" -> 0.258425, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.910458, "c1_3" -> 0.0203598, "c2_1" -> 0.267614, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.675246|>, <|"Gene" -> "c", "c1_1" -> 0.331962, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.389325, "c1_3" -> 0.673205, "c2_1" -> 0.346972, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.784099|>, <|"Gene" -> "d", "c1_1" -> 0.460994, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.376045, "c1_3" -> 0.0499006, "c2_1" -> 0.165925, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.547476|>, <|"Gene" -> "c", "c1_1" -> 0.331962, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.389325, "c1_3" -> 0.673205, "c2_1" -> 0.346972, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.784099|>, <|"Gene" -> "c", "c1_1" -> 0.331962, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.389325, "c1_3" -> 0.673205, "c2_1" -> 0.346972, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.784099|>, <|"Gene" -> "a", "c1_1" -> 0.0862185, 
  "c1_2" -> 0.591649, "c1_3" -> 0.119653, "c2_1" -> 0.329605, 
  "c2_2" -> 0.953679|>}





 d2=Dataset@{<|"Gene" -> "h", "f1" -> 0.93386, "f2" -> 0.684875, 
  "f3" -> 0.599702|>, <|"Gene" -> "b", "f1" -> 0.93083, 
  "f2" -> 0.735748, "f3" -> 0.586162|>, <|"Gene" -> "j", 
  "f1" -> 0.373753, "f2" -> 0.246, 
  "f3" -> 0.150022|>, <|"Gene" -> "d", "f1" -> 0.945271, 
  "f2" -> 0.553761, "f3" -> 0.658329|>, <|"Gene" -> "k", 
  "f1" -> 0.35108, "f2" -> 0.575718, 
  "f3" -> 0.337428|>, <|"Gene" -> "f", "f1" -> 0.525761, 
  "f2" -> 0.198373, "f3" -> 0.168825|>, <|"Gene" -> "d", 
  "f1" -> 0.525761, "f2" -> 0.198373, 
  "f3" -> 0.168825|>, <|"Gene" -> "d", "f1" -> 0.525761, 
  "f2" -> 0.198373, "f3" -> 0.168825|>, <|"Gene" -> "a", 
  "f1" -> 0.525761, "f2" -> 0.198373, 
  "f3" -> 0.168825|>, <|"Gene" -> "b", "f1" -> 0.525761, 
  "f2" -> 0.198373, "f3" -> 0.168825|>}
```

---

@Kuba's approach (prior to this update), is certainly more succinct and the syntax is a bit foreign to me.  It does merge the data sets together and take the mean; however, it does not handle duplicate IDs. The replicate part of this question was added during the update so naturally it was not included in his answer.

[image]

## Desired exact result

The desired results on the given example data in order of transformations is as follows.

- common ids of both sets: `{"a", "b", "d", "f"}`
- combining (tack on `d2` to the end of `d1`
- find duplicate rows, e.g. in `d1` there are two rows with the id "a", four with "c", etc
- average those duplicates together by id, e.g. for rows with the id "a", looking at only column "c1_1", then the average would be $(0.0862184+0.0862184)/2$.
- find replicates in the column header (e.g. "c1_1", "c1_2", "c1_3" are replicates of "c1")
- average them together, so for "a" and replicates of "c1", $(0.0862184+0.591649+0.119653)/3$.

e.g. produces the result of the example given above

Answer (score 7):

We can get a long way by (inner) joining across the common gene keys using `JoinAcross`, grouping by gene, and then averaging across each group:

```
JoinAcross[d1, d2, "Gene"][GroupBy["Gene"] /* Values, Merge[Mean]]
```

[image: joined dataset]

What remains is to merge and average the similarly named columns.  This is really the crux of this question.  Here is a helper function that does the job:

```
averageKeys =
  KeyValueMap[<| StringReplace[#, n__~~"_"~~___ :> n] -> #2 |> &] /* Merge[Mean];
```

Here it is in action:

```
<| "Gene" -> "x"
 , "c1_1" -> 10, "c1_2" -> 40, "c1_3" -> 40
 , "c2_1" -> 10, "c2_2" -> 20
 , "f1" -> 1, "f2" -> 2, "f3" -> 3
 |> // averageKeys

(* <| "Gene" -> "x", "c1" -> 30, "c2" -> 15, "f1" -> 1, "f2" -> 2, "f3" -> 3|> *)
```

We can then supplement the original query to use this helper function and obtain the final result:

```
JoinAcross[d1, d2, "Gene"][GroupBy["Gene"] /* Values, Merge[Mean], averageKeys]
```

[image: final result]

If row order matters, we can sort them after the fact:

```
%[Sort]
```

[image: sorted final result]

... or adjust the full query to include a sorting stage:

```
JoinAcross[d1,d2,"Gene"][GroupBy["Gene"] /* Values /* Query[Sort], Merge[Mean], averageKeys]
```

[image: sorted final result]

`Sort` is wrapped in `Query` to ensure that it happens after the inner operations are complete (i.e. to convert `Sort` from a "descending" operator into an "ascending" one).

**More than two datasets**

The technique can be generalized to accommodate more than two datasets.  Given the additional dataset:

```
d3 = { <| "Gene" -> "a", "g" -> 1 |>, <| "Gene" -> "b", "g" -> 2 |>} // Dataset;
```

Then:

```
{d1, d2, d3} //
Map[Query[GroupBy["Gene"] /* Values, Merge[Mean], averageKeys]] //
Fold[JoinAcross[#, #2, "Gene"]&] //
Sort
```

[image: three-way join dataset screenshot]

This approach is superior to the earlier expression on two counts: 1) it supports multiple datasets and 2) it is more robust when it comes to handling duplicate keys within the source datasets.

Comment: The very first answer with `JoinAcross` that makes sense to me. I was wondering where this function may be useful. Up to now I considered it a retarded sister of `GroupBy+Merge`. :) +1

Comment: @WReach I have many questions about your answer. In no particular order, `JoinAcross`. My own answer, which appears to be an excessively verbose equivalent to yours, works with an arbitrary number of `Dataset` objects. `JoinAcross` requires the first two arguments be separate lists. if you had a variable `d={d1,d2,...}` how could you alter `JoinAcross` to handle that? I feel like this is a need for `Fold` but I never been able to get `Fold` to work as I wanted to. Also  could you possibly elaborate on your use of composition `/*`?

Comment: If the join criteria are identical for all datasets, we can use something like `Fold[JoinAcross[##, "Gene"] &, {d1, d2, d3}]`.  Often it is the case that the join critieria are _not_ identical or there are key collisions between the datasets.  In such cases we need to explicitly nest the `JoinAcross` expressions.  `/*` essentially chains operators together so that they are applied in order.  In queries, the use can be subtle -- see [(98193)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98193/142) for discussion.

Comment: @WReach unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for `Dataset` objects? Why are some methods unable to work with `Dataset` if it is just an association wrapped with a different head?

Comment: @WReach Also what is with the double slot?

Comment: @WReach So if I encapsulate the `KeyValueMap` in the operator form of `Query` as follows: `data[All, KeyValueMap[...]/*Merge[Mean]]`, it works. Could you possibly break down that function though? I get the string replace patterns. What I do not understand is why 1.) you use a delayed assignment, 2.) why you wrap the string replace in an association and then use a pure function. It comes to reason that `#2` is the value associated with the given `Key` correct? By why this notation? Also where to read more about `inner`?

Comment: I added a section demonstrating the use of fold across multiple datasets.  The revised approach is more robust in the face of duplicate keys.  `##` references all arguments, in this case it is shorthand for `#, #2`.  I don't use delayed assignment -- perhaps you mean `:>`?  I use it instead of `->` to ensure that `n` is a local variable.  The notation `<| ... |> &` is simply defining a pure function that returns an association.  The term "inner" here comes from [relational joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).  I'm happy to continue discussion, but perhaps it should be in chat.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that `JoinAcross` is seriously broken in version 11.0.0 but works just fine in 11.0.1 and 10.x releases -- see the comments to [(129122)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129122/142).

Answer (score 5):

Applying `mergeData` results in:
[image]

Define the conditions in the data set:

```
bioKeys = Normal@Keys@First@Bio
conditions = {"c1", "c2"};
```

Acquire position of replicates via string search:

```
replicates = 
 Flatten@Position[bioKeys, #] & /@ 
    Flatten@StringCases[bioKeys, conditions[[#]] ~~ __] & /@ 
  Range@Length@conditions
```

Merge replicates:

```
mergedReplicates = 
 Bio[All, Flatten[bioKeys[[#]] & /@ replicates[[#]], 1] /* <|
      conditions[[#]] -> Mean|>] & /@ Range@Length@conditions
```

[image]

Delete individual replicates:

```
Bio = Bio[All, Delete[Partition[Flatten@replicates, 1]]];
```

Add in the merged replicate columns:

```
Table[Bio = 
   Dataset@MapThread[
     Append, {Normal@Bio, Thread[Normal@mergedReplicates[[i]]]}], {i, 
   Length@mergedReplicates}];
```

[image]

## Confirm

Let's look gene "a" which has both replicates and duplicates.

Getting gene "a" replicates for condition 1:

```
d1[All, {"Gene", "c1_1", "c1_2", "c1_3"}][Select[#Gene == "a" &]]
```

[image]

Averaging those rows together:

```
d1[All, {"Gene", "c1_1", "c1_2", "c1_3"}][
  Select[#Gene == "a" &]][Mean]
```

[image]

Average those columns together:

```
Mean[Normal[
   d1[All, {"Gene", "c1_1", "c1_2", "c1_3"}][Select[#Gene == "a" &]][
     Mean][Values]][[2 ;;]]]
```

[image]

and indeed that is the value in for gene "a" in column "c1".

## Main Functions

```
mergeData[Data_List] := Module[
  {keys, data, common, dupData},
  data = Data;
  keys = Normal@Keys@First@data[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@data;
  data = Table[
    With[{key = keys[[d]]}, data[[d]][SortBy[#[First@key] &]]], {d, 
     Length@data}];
  common = 
   Intersection[
    Table[With[{key = keys[[d]]}, data[[d]][All, #[First@key] &]], {d,
       Length@data}]];
  data = Table[
    With[{key = keys[[d]]}, 
     data[[d]][Select[MemberQ[common[[d]], #[First@key]] &]]], {d, 
     Length@data}];
  dupData = Table[DealWithDuplicates[data[[d]]], {d, Length@data}];
  data = Table[
    ReplaceDuplicatesWithMean[data[[d]], dupData[[d]][[1]], 
     dupData[[d]][[2]]], {d, Length@data}];
  data = DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, First] & /@ data;
  Return[JoinAcross @@ Append[data, First@First@keys]]
  ]
```

## Supporting Functions

```
DealWithDuplicates[data_] := Module[
  {keys, dupicateValues, duplicatePositions, duplicatesAveraged},
  keys = Normal@Keys@First@data;
  dupicateValues = 
   If[Length[#] > 1, First@#, Nothing] & /@ 
    Split@Normal@data[All, #[First@keys] &];
  duplicatePositions = 
   Flatten[#] & /@ (Position[Normal@data[All, #[First@keys] &], #] & /@
       dupicateValues);
  duplicatesAveraged = 
   data[duplicatePositions[[#]]][Mean] & /@ 
    Range[Length@duplicatePositions];
  Return[{duplicatePositions, duplicatesAveraged}]
  ]

ReplaceDuplicatesWithMean[data_, duplicatePositions_, 
  duplicateAveraged_] := Module[{temp},
  temp = data;
  Table[temp = 
    ReplacePart[
     temp, {First@duplicatePositions[[i]]} -> 
      Normal@duplicateAveraged[[i]]], {i, Length@duplicateAveraged}];
  Return[temp];
  ]

DeleteDuplicatesNotAveraged[data_, duplicatePositions_, 
  duplicateAveraged_] := Module[
  {minus, temp},
  temp = data;
  temp = Delete[temp, 
    duplicatePositions[[#, 2 ;;]] & /@ 
     Range@Length@duplicatePositions];
  Return[temp]
  ]
```

Comment: This is a long way to go for a relatively straightforward processing task. First of all if you find yourself using `Table` and `Part`, you're not using the features introduced in V10.

Comment: @alancalvitti That is the purpose of this post. I can do the processing task, sure. Yet it is not optimal. I am struggling to understand the internal syntax for objects with the `Head` `Dataset` . Hence the shoot out to @OneSquare for their answer on Slots (as variable named slots don't work so great).

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know what exactly is needed but this does most of what you seem to be after:

```
joined = Join[d1, d2];
merged = Values @ GroupBy[joined, #d &, Merge[Mean]]
```

[image]

```
merged // MaximalBy[Length]
```

[image]

and this is what your function does:

```
mergeDatasets[d1, d2]
```

[image]

Except it has strange value for (here) `d=5`, mine is an average while yours seems to keep the first record (for other `d` it takes average). Maybe that was your point, sorry but I lost the track.

Answer (score 2):

No need for all that, try a functional approach: this gets you 90% there - you may want to delete based on missing values to match to your preferred format

```
{d1 // GroupBy[Query@"Gene"], d2 // GroupBy[Query@"Gene"]} // 
    Merge[Merge[Mean]] // 
   Query[All, KeyDrop["Gene"] /* KeyMap[stringSplit["_"]] /* 
     keyGroupBy[First] /* Map[Values /* Mean]] // Dataset // Query[Transpose]
```

[image]

The `Transpose` is not necessary, but is a workaround to V11's highly compressed formatting. You can replace it with:

`// keyPushValues["Gene"]`  where

`keyPushValues[key_]:=Query[{Keys/*AssociationMap[Association[key->#1]&],Identity}]/*Query[Merge[Apply[Join]]]/*Values`

to get:

[image]

Note uses:

`keyGroupBy[f_][expr_]:=Association/@GroupBy[Normal[expr],Keys/*f]`

And

`stringSplit`, the operator version:

`stringSplit[str_String][expr_]:=StringSplit[expr,str]`

Comment: I'm going to take a while to digest your code up there. Can you please (please) describe, verbosely, your code and how it works?

Comment: @SumNeuron, a major advantage of functional approach is that it's a pipeline, that you can segment anywhere you want. Try each step in turn to see the effect, eg try `{d1 // GroupBy[Query@"Gene"], d2 // GroupBy[Query@"Gene"]} // 
  Merge[ Merge[Mean]] // Dataset`  -- it's unfortunate that `Dataset` has to be wrapped and `Normalized` so many times

Comment: @SumNeuron, unfortunately, Stackexchange is not conducive to tutoring, but reach me at my email, I'll be happy to give you a tutorial. In fact I'd like to start a Khan Academy thing for data.

Comment: sent the email :) Also will do. Why do you think that is?  this kind of dataset manipulation is common, so shouldn't there be a pretty succinct way of doing this?

Comment: Also this is throwing warnings all over :( I'm using v11 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

This answer takes a three step approach by querying the `Dataset`swithin `Module`.

1. Join and summarise the columns.
2. Get the sets of keys that need to be collapsed into one key.
3. Collapse the key sets from step 2 and drop the keys that form their basis.

`mergeAndClean` completes these steps.

```
mergeAndClean[ds1_Dataset, ds2_Dataset, idKey_] :=
 Module[{dsTemp, columnColapse},
  dsTemp =
   JoinAcross[ds1, ds2, idKey][
    GroupBy[#[idKey] &] /*
     Values,
    Transpose /*
     (Query[Join[{1 -> First}, (# -> Mean) & /@ Range[2, Length@Keys@#]]]@# &)];

  columnColapse = Normal@
    dsTemp[First /*
      Keys /*
      StringCases[LetterCharacter ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ "_" ~~ DigitCharacter] /*
      Apply[Join] /*
      GroupBy[StringTake[#, 2] &]];

  dsTemp[All,
   Function[{a},
     <|a, KeyValueMap[#1 -> Mean@a[[#2]] &]@columnColapse|>] /*
    KeyDrop[Flatten@Values@columnColapse]]
  ]
```

Then

```
mergeAndClean[d1, d2, "Gene"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Additional parameters can be added to pass in the merging function, the key pattern, and so on.

Hope this helps.