# Bioinformatics: RNA-seq and Gene Set Analysis Pipelines

Tags: systems-biology, bioinformatics

## Context

The decreasing price of high-throughput genome sequencing has skyrocketed its use.

[image: Rise in RNA-seq publications]

While Mathematica is a remarkable language, it does lag behind in some regards for various reasons; notably, Wolfram does not seem to have the same scale in community that other languages such as `R` has. Thus `R` users have seen the development of entire suites for processing genomic data, e.g. Bioconductor, Cufflinks, TopHat, Bowtie, Bowtie2, Samtools, STAR, BED tools, etc, etc.

While I will not attempt to recreate these tools in Mathematica, it may be of interest to the Bioinformaticians of the Wolfram community to have a collected source of useful questions, answers, functions, etc. that can be used following processing in the established pipelines.

It seems Mathematica's bioinformatics side is actually quite underdeveloped. Most of the features toted for Bioinformatics are applicable to most fields, and other than a hand full of functions like `GenomeData[]`,  I could only find one differentially expression package, here: [Maayan Lab](http://www.maayanlab.net/CD).

---

## RLink for established packages

- [Installing Bioconductor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128708/42578)

## Sequence Processing

- "[Sequence Alignment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceAlignment.html)" (basic string matching)
- Accepted [life science file formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ChemicalDataFormats.html)

## Gene List Pre-Processing

- [ID Swapping: Efficient use of a reference table to convert ID values.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128696/id-swapping-efficient-use-of-a-reference-table-to-convert-id-values)
- [Dataset Processing: efficient ways to clean and merge sets for Life Sciences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128519/dataset-processing-efficient-ways-to-clean-and-merge-sets-for-life-sciences)
- [Example of the above two used together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128712/42578)

## Differential Expression Analysis

- [Geometric approach to differential expression](http://www.maayanlab.net/CD/)

Comment: This seems very broad -- can you narrow down the question?  If the broad scope is intentional, then perhaps this would be better suited as a [blog post](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1)?

Comment: @WReach I havent seen other blog posts before so possible. I have, however, seen other broad questions like this that serve as central hubs for directing to specific sub-answers. Mr. Wizard does this quite often :)

Comment: The difference is that Mr Wizard normally focuses on the Mathematica context *not* the subject context.

Comment: @GordonCoale true. So what do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

## Gene List Pre-Processing

**ABOUT**:

In this example we have two gene lists, both from mice. One gene list contains columns of features, the other has condition replicates.

**GOAL**:

The goal is to

1. Convert the Ensembl IDs to gene names
2. Replaces the Ensembl IDs in our Datasets with gene names
3. Find those genes common to both Datasets and use only those records
4. Find duplicate gene names and average those rows together
5. Find replicates in our columns and merge those together
6. Combine these datasets into a single Dataset for easier handling

**NOTE**:

This example uses the code described and demonstrated here:

- [Dataset Processing: efficient ways to clean and merge sets for Life Sciences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128519/dataset-processing-efficient-ways-to-clean-and-merge-sets-for-life-sciences)
- [Dataset Processing: efficient ways to clean and merge sets for Life Sciences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128696/id-swapping-efficient-use-of-a-reference-table-to-convert-id-values)

The example data (because it is "clunky") is at the bottom of this post. An image of it is posted here for convenience.

[image: example data]

---

## Get our genes

```
geneList = 
  Normal@With[{slot = First@Normal@Keys@First@geneListFile}, 
    geneListFile[All, Slot[slot] &]];
geneList2 = 
  Normal@With[{slot = First@Normal@Keys@First@geneListFile2}, 
    geneListFile2[All, Slot[slot] &]];
```

[image]

---

## Set up for ID conversion

```
speciesCommonName = "mouse";
speciesCommonNameAssociations = <|"HUMAN" -> "hg", "MOUSE" -> "mm", 
   "YEAST" -> "sc", "RAT" -> "rn"|>;
speciesEncodedName = 
  Lookup[ToUpperCase@speciesCommonName]@
   speciesCommonNameAssociations;
referenceFileName = 
  First@FileNames[___ ~~ speciesEncodedName ~~ ___ ~~ ".csv", 
    NotebookDirectory[]];
```

---

## Load reference file

```
referenceFile = SemanticImport@referenceFileName;
keys = Normal@Keys@First@referenceFile;
data = referenceFile[All, 
   Select[keys, StringContainsQ[#, "Gene"] &]];
\[ScriptCapitalA] = 
  AssociationThread[#[[;; , 1]], #[[;; , 2]]] &@Normal@data[Values];
```

---

## Convert Ensembl IDs to gene names

```
genes = Lookup[\[ScriptCapitalA], #] & /@ geneList;
genes2 = Lookup[\[ScriptCapitalA], #] & /@ geneList2;
```

### [image]

## Replace Ensembl ID with gene name

```
d1 = Dataset@
   MapThread[
    Prepend,  { Normal@geneListFile, Thread["Genes" -> genes]}];
d2 = Dataset@
   MapThread[
    Prepend,  { Normal@geneListFile2, Thread["Genes" -> genes2]}];
```

[image]

---

## Functions for merging data

```
DealWithDuplicates[data_] := 
 Module[{keys, dupicateValues, duplicatePositions, 
   duplicatesAveraged}, keys = Normal@Keys@First@data;
  dupicateValues = 
   If[Length[#] > 1, First@#, Nothing] & /@ 
    Split@Normal@data[All, #[First@keys] &];
  duplicatePositions = 
   Flatten[#] & /@ (Position[Normal@data[All, #[First@keys] &], #] & /@
       dupicateValues);
  duplicatesAveraged = 
   data[duplicatePositions[[#]]][Mean] & /@ 
    Range[Length@duplicatePositions];
  Return[{duplicatePositions, duplicatesAveraged}]]

ReplaceDuplicatesWithMean[data_, duplicatePositions_, 
  duplicateAveraged_] := Module[{temp}, temp = data;
  Table[temp = 
    ReplacePart[
     temp, {First@duplicatePositions[[i]]} -> 
      Normal@duplicateAveraged[[i]]], {i, Length@duplicateAveraged}];
  Return[temp];]

DeleteDuplicatesNotAveraged[data_, duplicatePositions_, 
  duplicateAveraged_] := Module[{minus, temp}, temp = data;
  temp = Delete[temp, 
    duplicatePositions[[#, 2 ;;]] & /@ 
     Range@Length@duplicatePositions];
  Return[temp]]

mergeData[Data_List] := 
 Module[{keys, data, common, dupData}, data = Data;
  keys = Normal@Keys@First@data[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@data;
  data = Table[
    With[{key = keys[[d]]}, data[[d]][SortBy[#[First@key] &]]], {d, 
     Length@data}];
  common = 
   Intersection[
    Table[With[{key = keys[[d]]}, data[[d]][All, #[First@key] &]], {d,
       Length@data}]];
  data = Table[
    With[{key = keys[[d]]}, 
     data[[d]][Select[MemberQ[common[[d]], #[First@key]] &]]], {d, 
     Length@data}];
  dupData = Table[DealWithDuplicates[data[[d]]], {d, Length@data}];
  data = Table[
    ReplaceDuplicatesWithMean[data[[d]], dupData[[d]][[1]], 
     dupData[[d]][[2]]], {d, Length@data}];
  data = DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, First] & /@ data;
  Return[JoinAcross @@ Append[data, First@First@keys]]]
```

---

## Merge Data

```
Bio = mergeData[{d1, d2}]
```

[image]

```
bioKeys = Normal@Keys@First@Bio
conditions = {"condition1", "condition2"};
replicates = 
 Flatten@Position[bioKeys, #] & /@ 
    Flatten@StringCases[bioKeys, conditions[[#]] ~~ __] & /@ 
  Range@Length@conditions;

mergedReplicates = Bio[All, Flatten[bioKeys[[#]] & /@ replicates[[#]], 1] /* <|
  conditions[[#]] -> Mean|>] & /@ Range@Length@conditions;


Bio = Bio[All, Delete[Partition[Flatten@replicates, 1]]];
Table[Bio = Dataset@MapThread[
 Append, {Normal@Bio, Thread[Normal@mergedReplicates[[i]]]}], {i,Length@mergedReplicates}];
```

### [image]

### Example Data

```
geneListFile=Dataset@{<|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000064842", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000051951", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102851", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103377", 
  "Feature1" -> 60, "Feature2" -> 35, 
  "Feature3" -> 75|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000104017", 
  "Feature1" -> 550, "Feature2" -> 360, 
  "Feature3" -> 560|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103025", 
  "Feature1" -> 7, "Feature2" -> 4, 
  "Feature3" -> 3|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000089699", 
  "Feature1" -> 36, "Feature2" -> 34, 
  "Feature3" -> 49|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103201", 
  "Feature1" -> 144, "Feature2" -> 107, 
  "Feature3" -> 206|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103147", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103161", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 1|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102331", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102348", 
  "Feature1" -> 16, "Feature2" -> 10, 
  "Feature3" -> 15|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102592", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000088333", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 1, 
  "Feature3" -> 1|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102343", 
  "Feature1" -> 2, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102948", 
  "Feature1" -> 0, "Feature2" -> 0, 
  "Feature3" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000025900", 
  "Feature1" -> 28, "Feature2" -> 23, 
  "Feature3" -> 30|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000104123", 
  "Feature1" -> 2, "Feature2" -> 3, "Feature3" -> 0|>}

geneListFile2=Dataset@{<|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", "condition1_1" -> 0, 
  "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000064842", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102851", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 60, "condition1_2" -> 35, "condition1_3" -> 75, 
  "condition2_1" -> 60, 
  "condition2_2" -> 35|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 550, "condition1_2" -> 360, "condition1_3" -> 560,
   "condition2_1" -> 550, 
  "condition2_2" -> 360|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103025", 
  "condition1_1" -> 7, "condition1_2" -> 4, "condition1_3" -> 3, 
  "condition2_1" -> 7, 
  "condition2_2" -> 4|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 36, "condition1_2" -> 34, "condition1_3" -> 49, 
  "condition2_1" -> 36, 
  "condition2_2" -> 34|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103201", 
  "condition1_1" -> 144, "condition1_2" -> 107, "condition1_3" -> 206,
   "condition2_1" -> 144, 
  "condition2_2" -> 107|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103147", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000103161", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 1, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 16, "condition1_2" -> 10, "condition1_3" -> 15, 
  "condition2_1" -> 16, 
  "condition2_2" -> 10|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102592", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000100538", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 1, "condition1_3" -> 1, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 1|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000101117", 
  "condition1_1" -> 2, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 2, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000100204", 
  "condition1_1" -> 0, "condition1_2" -> 0, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 0, 
  "condition2_2" -> 0|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000084668", 
  "condition1_1" -> 28, "condition1_2" -> 23, "condition1_3" -> 30, 
  "condition2_1" -> 28, 
  "condition2_2" -> 23|>, <|"Genes" -> "ENSMUSG00000102693", 
  "condition1_1" -> 2, "condition1_2" -> 3, "condition1_3" -> 0, 
  "condition2_1" -> 2, "condition2_2" -> 3|>}
```