# RLink: How to install R packages such as Bioconductor

Tags: rlink, bioinformatics

I would like to install Bioconductor R packages. However I get error that the variables are not found... I really have no idea how `RLink` so I do appreciate your assistance.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
REvaluate["source(\"http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R\"); biocLite(\" DESeq \")"]
```

[image]

I have already installed these packages via R on my computer. I thought it may help to install them via RLink incase Mathematica puts them somewhere special. Trying to load the packages also does not work:

[image]

It works in R

[image]

R Version in RLink is not the most up-to-date but it should not be an issue...

```
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
```

Comment: The standard way to install R packages is via `install.packages`. But installing packages in this way works via RLink only on Windows. On other platforms, you need to use the R's command line for that - then you can work with installed packages via RLink. What OS are you on?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I am on a Mac. Yes, normally install packages work like that. To get the bioconductor packages, you use these commands... then Library(DESeq) https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq.html

Comment: Then I suggest that you install this from R's command line. After that, hopefully you should be able to work with the package using RLink. Also, I suggest to use the external R distribution with RLink, since the one that comes with RLink is pretty old. The steps to set this up can be found [here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin see updated question

Comment: Well, in this case the error seems to be on the R side, as reported by RLink. Are you sure you did successfully install the package? Again, one way to test is to type the same `library(DESeq)` in R console for your R distribution and see what happens.

Comment: One other thing to make sure is that you are using the right version of R with RLink. You may test this via `REvaluate["R.Version()"]`, to make sure you use the one you want (rather than, for example, the default one that comes with RLink). You need to point to specific R via `"RHomeLocation"` option in `InstallR`, if you use the external R distro.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin so how do I do this? (sorry for being pathetically unaware of RLink)

Comment: Ok, so I've done that myself, and the problem is really not on the RLink side. The same issue you get also when trying in R console. You need to execute these commands from R command line: `biocLite()`, and then `biocLite("DESeq2")`. They will update the version of DESeq2 that you installed, as well as dependencies. After that, it worked with RLink, at least to the point that relevant library gets loaded with `REvaluate["library(DESeq2)"]`. Here is the relevant [link](https://www.biostars.org/p/157305/)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Sorry I am still not quite sure what you mean and I think we may have a miscommunication. Everything is already installed via R. I can already run all of Bioconductor in R, and do so regularly. The problem is trying to run R via RLink in Mathematica..

Comment: Then I really don't know. What I meant was that I installed this on my R distro (3.1.1), and then initially had the same issue you reported. Then, I followed that link I gave, ran those commands, and had no issues after that neither in R nor in Mathematica / RLink. The error message you are getting seems to indicate that the problems are on the R side. All I can suggest is to, once again, make sure that RLink runs the proper version of R.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin so how does one select which version of R to use in Mathematica?

Comment: It is described in the link I gave in my first comment. Basically, you use options "RHomeLocation", and possibly  "RVersion". You can look up the details in that link. Basically, on a fresh kernel, you execute `SetEnvironment[
 "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" ->  "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"]` and then `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> 
  "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", "RVersion" -> 3]`. The paths on your machine may differ, although I believe these are the default ones. You can test then with `REvaluate["R.Version()"]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I didn't try `RHomeLocation` as on the documentation it is only for windows?

Comment: Well, you are right. This is an oversight on my side, I should've made that more automatic. Problem is, I never had enough dedicated time to improve on RLink since it was released, and such a feature needs some time to be automated and tested properly on a variety of systems. So in practice, `"RHomeLocation"` works on all systems but on Linux and Mac requires a bit of extra work (on Linux one may need to install extra library, which was another obstacle to full automation) on the side of the user. Which is what the setup guide kindly written by Szabolcs, that I linked to,  describes how to do.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin any luck for Macs?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow the question. If you do the steps listed in that link of Szabolcs I gave, it all should work for you right away, right now. If you mean the automation of those steps, then there is some chance that I could get some time to work on automating this process on Macs soon.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I was curious as to if you may have made any progress with specifying home location for R on mac. This issue is the Mac advice given by Szabolcs for v10 fails to load dynamic libraries. I am not the only one with this issue. Where would I even begin to trouble shoot this?

Comment: I actually did some work on that, but unfortunately that had to be stopped  / postponed for 11.2 due to conflicting things that were considered of higher priority. Hopefully, there will be no more delays with this, although 11.2 is still rather far away, admittedly. But, have you carefully read through Szabolcs's advice on his page? He has a section for modern OS X versions,  [here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html#elcap). It did work for everyone who tried it so far, as far as I am informed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yes it seems my system is missing the key file... so I guess I will have to maybe try a clean install.

Comment: Which file do you mean?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin libjri.jnilib

Comment: You may also get it from [here](https://rforge.net/rJava/files/), mac binary link at the bottom. Just download the archive, unpack and go to jri subfolder, it's there. Just keep in mind that the release version won't work with bundled R, only with external one - and in any case, only after you perform the procedure described by Szabolcs.